# Angularjs:how to show td empty, when value is empty for that column in table

Tags: angularjs

When previous td is empty, the next td values are getting diplayed in previous td. i have tried below approach, but its not solving my problem.

```
<td class="errorDescription col-sm-3">
    <span ng-if="utfDataRequest.parsedValue"> {{utfDataRequest.parsedValue}}</span>
    <span ng-if="!utfDataRequest.parsedValue"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Why do you need `<span ng-if="!utfDataRequest.parsedValue"></span>`? I don't really understand the issue

Comment: currently i am writing this way, but when parsedValue is empty, datatype value is getting displayed under parsedValue, i want to show parsedValue as empty and datatype value should come under datatype 
<td class="errorDescription col-sm-3">{{ utfDataRequest.parsedValue}}</td>
        <td class="errorDescription col-sm-2">{{utfDataRequest.dataType}}</td>

Comment: Like a placeholder? `<span ng-if="!utfDataRequest.parsedValue">&nbsp;</span>` maybe? If not, please [edit] the question and include more details - Show us more relevant parts of the view, include the data from the controller and the expected output

Comment: I feel like we're missing a broader context.  Can we see the full table definition, including any `ng-repeats`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to just put in your coed `<td><span ng-if="utfDataRequest.parsedValue"> {{utfDataRequest.parsedValue}}</span></td>` because if parsedValue is empty then nothing will display in `<span ng-if="utfDataRequest.parsedValue"> {{utfDataRequest.parsedValue}}</span>`
so your code is

```
<td class="errorDescription col-sm-3">
    <span ng-if="utfDataRequest.parsedValue"> {{utfDataRequest.parsedValue}}</span>
</td>
```

Comment: i tried, but still datatype value is coming under parsedValue if parsedValue is empty

Comment: @RuchiGupta can you suggest which type value come's through database

Comment: string type value is coming from database

Comment: put screenshort or other way to show by us  because no idea we get from your comment